# Ruby pluck second number from this scraped HTML (wombat)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, web-scraping, string-parsing

Here's a section of HTML I'm trying to pull some info from:

```
<div class="pagination">
  <p>
    <span>Showing</span>
    1-30
    of 3744
    <span>results</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

I just want to store `3744` from the bit I pull (everything inside the `<p>`), but I'm having a hard time since the `of 3744` doesn't have any CSS styling and I don't understand XPaths at all :)

`<span>Showing</span>1-30\nof 3744<span>results</span>`

How would you parse the above string to only retrieve the total number of results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as it always looks the same you could also use `#scan` to get just the last number.

```
str = '<div class="pagination">
           <p>
             <span>Showing</span>
                1-30
                of 3744
             <span>results</span>
           </p>
       </div>'
str.scan(/\d+/).pop.to_i
#=> 3744
```

**Update Explanation of how it works**

The `scan` will pull an `Array` of all the numbers e.g. `["1","30","3744"]` then it will `pop` the last element from the `Array` `"3744"` and then convert that to an integer `3744`.

Please note that if the number you want is not the last element in the `Array` then this will not work as you want e.g.

```
str = '<div class="pagination">
           <p>
             <span>Showing</span>
                1-30
                of 3744
             <span>results 14</span>
           </p>
       </div>'
str.scan(/\d+/).pop.to_i
#=> 14
```

As you can see since I added the number 14 to the results span this is now the last number in the Array and your results are off. So you could modify it to something like this:

```
 str.gsub(/\s+/,'').scan(/\d+-\d+of(\d+)/).flatten.pop.to_i
 #=> 3744
```

What this will do is remove all spaces with `gsub` then look for a pattern that equates to something along the lines of `#{1,}-#{1,}of#{1,}` and capture the last group `#=> [["3744"]]` then `flatten` the `Array` `#=> ["3744"]` then `pop` and convert to `Integer`. This seems like a better solution as it will make sure to match the "of ####" section everytime.

Comment: @KyleCarlson updated my answer with an explanation of how it works.

Comment: Brilliant. I'd give you two points if I could. Here's the ruby-doc link for anyone who's interested: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-scan

Comment: @KyleCarlson added a little more just so that you can see possible caveats with the original and a possible better way to handle this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use regexp look example [`Rubular`](http://rubular.com/r/2JFwlq8PG0):

```
<span>\w+<\/span>\d\-\d+\\[a-z]+\s(\d+)<span>\w+<\/span>
```

Match groups:

```
3744
```